# Which is the most suitable non-parametric test (and post-hoc)for a heavily umbalanced groups (3, 15 and 11 observations)?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

I am comparing soil properties among different geological substrates.
I have only 3 observations in one category (karst soils), 15 observations in sedimentary terrains and 11 observations in crystalline terrains. My variables are non-normal, however homocedastic (according to Levene's test). Which would be the most suitable non-parametric and post hoc tests in this situation?

Many thanks

Comment: Unless you’re looking to detect only rather large differences, you don’t have enough data, particularly in that smallest group. A way to remedy this is to use Bayesian methods that have a prior distribution, but a danger there is that a prior will be highly influential when you have little data, meaning that a poor choice of prior will ruin your day. // I wouldn’t trust a variance test. It’s likely that you’re failing to reject due to a small sample size, not because of variances that are equal.

Comment: Hi, @Dave. Thanks for your comment. Could you please provide me a reference for "only rather large differences"? I ask because it is exactly the case for me: the group with n=3 is presumably very different from the others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are several possible approaches, which may illustrate the difficulty
in finding significance among small differences in group means, when sample sizes are as small as yours.

**Fictitious data.** Suppose we have fictitious gamma distributed data sampled in R, with group
sizes $3, 15,$ and $11,$ as you specify, and population means
far enough apart to see some significant effects. [Of course, in an actual application, we would never know
the distributions of the three populations for sure.]

```
set.seed(2021)
x1 = rgamma( 3, 3, .1)
x2 = rgamma(15, 3, .3)
x3 = rgamma(11, 3, .5)

summary(x1); length(x1); sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  20.47   21.78   23.10   24.86   27.06   31.01 
[1] 3            # sample size
[1] 5.486118     # sample SD
summary(x2); length(x2); sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.281   4.466   9.253  10.702  18.199  19.945 
[1] 15
[1] 7.350433
summary(x3); length(x3); sd(x3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.5353  2.0220  4.5508  4.8006  6.6338 10.7546 
[1] 11
[1] 3.351256
```

Here is are boxplots of the three sample; narrower boxes indicate
smaller sample sizes. Red `X`'s show sample means. [With only three observations, the boxplot for `x1` is problematic.]

```
x = c(x1,x2,x3)
g = rep(1:3, c(3,15,11))

boxplot(x~g, horizontal=T, varwidth=T, col="skyblue2")
 points(c(mean(x1),mean(x2),mean(x3)), 1:3, pch="X", col="red")
```

[image]

**Results from a Kruskal-Wallis test.** A Kruskal-Wallis test shows clearly (P-value $0.005 < 0.5 = 5\%)$
that at least one of the groups
stochastically dominates another. [Because sample SDs differ so
widely it is not strictly accurate to say that population medians
differ.]

```
kruskal.test(x ~ g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 10.696, df = 2, 
 p-value = 0.004759
```

**ANOVA without equal-variance assumption.** Although data are not normal, we might wonder what P-value we would
get from the `oneway.test` procedure in R, which assumes normality, but
not equal group variances. The P-value is not much different than for the Kruskal-Wallis test.

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means 
        (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 17.858, num df = 2.0000, denom df = 5.5308,
p-value = 0.003863
```

If we want to look only at the P-value, we can use `$`-notation:

```
pv.obs = oneway.test(x ~ g)$p.val;  pv.obs
[1] 0.003862857
```

**A simulated permutation test.** Whether or not we trust the F-statistic of `oneway.test` to have
an F-distribution, we might argue that the test statistic is
a useful way to show how far apart sample means are, taking
their variances into account. Then we might take the P-value
as a reasonable metric for a permutation test. The
distribution of that metric can be approximated by permuting
the $3+15+11=29$ observations among the three groups. [In R this
is accomplished by repeatedly scrambling the elements of `g` by using `sample(g)`.] The simulated permutation test gives
P-value $0.046.$

```
set.seed(1106)
pv = replicate(10^5, oneway.test(x~sample(g))$p.val)
mean(pv <= pv.obs)
[1] 0.04634
```

Notice that while we have used computations from a normal-based test for the 'metric', the P-value of the permutation test
comes from simulation, not from a normality assumption.
The permutation test, which does not assume normality, barely
finds significant differences at the 5% level.

[It would be somewhat more common to use the F-statistic from
each of the 100,000 runs as the metric of the permutation test, but
in this case the degrees of freedom vary somewhat depending on
the sample variances of the three permuted groups.]

***Note:*** (1) *Ad hoc* tests would depend on what kind of main test
you choose to use to compare the three groups. In any case, you should use a method that
protects against 'false discovery' upon repeated tests with
the same data. For example, you might use the Bonferroni method with Welch two-sample t tests, if you choose to use `oneway.test`. You might use Tukey's HSD *ad hoc* tests if you use a standard one-way ANOVA, assuming equal variances. Etc.

(2) I agree with @Dave that, with such a small amount of data, a
Bayesian approach might be preferable---especially, if prior
experience with such data provides clues toward a reasonable prior
distribution.

(3) In case there is any doubt about the validity of a permutation test using P-value as a metric, we
show that when applied to *normal* data, it gives
very nearly the same
P-value as does `oneway.test`.

```
set.seed(2021)
y1 = rnorm(15, 70, 10)
y2 = rnorm(15, 80, 10)
y3 = rnorm(15, 90, 10)
y=c(y1,y2,y3);  gg = rep(1:3, each=15)
PV.OBS = oneway.test(y~gg)$p.val; PV.OBS
[1] 0.01094681

PV = replicate(10^5, oneway.test(y~sample(gg))$p.val)
mean(PV <= PV.OBS
[1] 0.01027
2*sd(PV <= PV.OBS)/sqrt(10^5)
[1] 0.0006376403  # 95% margin of simulation error
```

Comment: Hi @BruceET, thanks for having prepared all these tips. I ran all suggestions. Interestingly, results were quite similar regardless of the method (also using classical and Welch's ANOVA - In fact, I found out that the residuals of my variables were normal, which is not the case for the raw variables.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing @Dave, statistical tests are to be avoided in this situation, and in general they fail to answer the "how much effect" question.  Compatibility (aka confidence; credible intervals for a Bayesian analysis) intervals are called for.  These expose the difficulty of the task (i.e., how much you don't know) when N=3 in one of the groups.  You can use the proportional odds model (a generalization of the Kruskal-Wallis test) to get confidence intervals for 3 different odds ratios for the pairwise comparisons.

Comment: Hi, @FrankHarrel. Thanks a lot for your excellent comment and suggestion. Unfortunately, I did not manage to use the proportional odds ratio yet: I could not run the code as a found in your BBR couse book (https://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf). Well, I am not too advanced in R, so I am really going through your YT BBR videos. Best Regards